# Is it possible to use my Raspberry Pi as an ethernet to USB adapter?

Tags: pi-3b+

I am trying to install various linux distros on my MacBook Air and MacBook Pro machines. They often require an ethernet connection for the installation. Instead of paying for and waiting for an adapter (because the Mac machines do not have ethernet ports), is there a way I could use my Pi in the place of an adapter? I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! The USB (which is a Hub) cannot act as a host. It may be possible with a Zero or A, but even this is impracticable.

But then your question is predicated on falsehood - you **DO NOT** require an ethernet connection for installation. You can easily install from an image on USB, but this is not a Pi question.

Comment: I was having a lot of problems installing Broadcom Wireless drivers for more than one distro without internet access re this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Also, it is best to be connected to the internet for installing Arch Linux. I may have been able to tether my machine with an Android phone. I tried with an iPhone but did not succeed. The ethernet adapter to USB worked.